# Force html table to use colgroup widths

Tags: html-table, width

Here is a sample: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8TdK/6/)

I have a table with 3 columns. Each should have 500px. But my table is resized to fit within the parent div (600px).

The width of my table should be 1500 (3x500) and a scrollbar should be displayed in parent div. How can I resolve this without adding a "width=XXX"?

```
<div id="container">
<table id="table">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 500px"></col>
        <col style="width: 500px"></col>
        <col style="width: 500px"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Putting ``min-width`` instead of ``width`` in your ``col`` tags works in Firefox.  However, apparently due to undefined behaviour in the CSS2.1 spec, it hasn't been implemented (and doesn't work) in at least Chrome.  (IE and Safari don't support it either according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width - I can't test those though).

Answer (score 0):

Apply `min-width` to the `table` tag (it doesn't work on `col` as explained in my comment on the OP).

Updated CSS:

```
#table {
    table-layout:fixed;
    margin:3px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    min-width: 1500px;
}
```

Tested in Chrome and Firefox, and should be widely supported (according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/minmaxwh)).

*Edit* I've realised this answer doesn't actually answer your question, as it works around the col tag problem rather than solving it. I hope it helps anyway though.